# Does $(1+x/n)e^x$ uniformly converge in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Does the sequence $f_n(x)=e^x(1+x/n)$ converge uniformly on **R**? What would be the function it converges to if it does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it converges obviously simply toward $e^x$ (fix x and make n tends to $+\infty$)
the difference is $e^x\frac{x}{n}$ that is obviously not bounded for all x.
So you have no uniform convergence.